# Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken is not a function in react native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, mixpanel

I would like to integrate Mixpanel with React Native,
I used this github source
https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel

I tried all the same as described but I got this messages

```
Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken is not a function
```

And `'Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken' is undefined)`

```
    var Mixpanel = require('react-native-mixpanel');

     componentDidMount() {
        console.log('============>', Mixpanel) // it returns object 
        Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken('xxx');
    }
```

[image]

I tried many times with no success.
App launches successfully but stops in the screen I used Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken('xxx')

Thank you.

Comment: Try `Mixpanel.default.sharedInstanceWithToken` or change `require` to `import Mixpanel from 'react-native-mixpanel'`

Comment: Thank you, but now I got this error "Mixpanel instance was not initialized yet, please run initialize() and wait for its promise to resolve before calling track(...)" but there is no such function

Comment: I just walked through code of this library. You don't need to call `initialize()` by yourself, it's done for you when you call `sharedInstanceWithToken`, but you need to note that this function return promise, so you need to use `then` before you call another methods, for i.e. 
```Mixpanel.default.sharedInstanceWithToken(MY_TOKEN).then(() => { // there use another methods })```

Answer (score 1):

As @savelichalex mentioned in the comments using this will work:

```js
const Mixpanel = require('react-native-mixpanel');
Mixpanel.default.sharedInstanceWithToken('MY_TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps me.
I created `react-native-mixpanel.js` file in `__mocks__` folder.
And put there:

```js
export default {
  sharedInstanceWithToken: jest.fn(),
};
```